# DialogFragment is not using my desired theme

Tags: android, android-context, android-dialogfragment, android-styles

I have a problem with Themes and Styles in Android when using different Android versions.

So the main problem is that I have a DialogFragment popping up at some point in the application and it contains an `EditText`. The AlertDialog is created like this:

```
AlertDialog dialog =  new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setPositiveButton ...
```

and the EditText is created and added like this:

```
editor = new EditText(getActivity());
dialog.setView(editor);
```

On my Lollipop device, the `EditText` has a bottom line with my desired color. (c1 in the list below).

But on my Android 4.3 device, it has the standard ugly blue bottom line.

My application has an apptheme that defines (among others) these items:

```
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/c1</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/c2</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/c3</item>

    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/c1</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/c2</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/c3</item>
```

The dialog fragments are started from an activity inheriting this app theme and I'm always using the regular getActivity() as Context.

So has anyone experienced this? I think it should automatically use the correct colors (through colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated and colorControlHighlight) but they are ignored.

I'm using `appcompat 22.2.0` btw.

Thanks for any input on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by using an `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText` instead of a regular Edittext. It does now use the correct Material design style.

Comment: Might as well use all appcompat widget.  I ended up using AppCompatButton, AppCompatImageView, etc.

Comment: Well, I have experimented with the same thing, but apparently, most of these views will use their AppCompat version automatically, if the Theme is an AppCompat theme. So for "most" of them, it doesn't make a difference. (Shouldn't for editText either, but might be different since it's within a DialogFragment). See this post for some information on this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35009532/difference-between-android-framework-widgets-and-their-appcompat-version