# Difference between Android Framework widgets and their AppCompat version

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I have lately noticed that there are AppCompat versions of most View types in Android, for example `ListView` / `ListViewCompat`, `Button` / `AppCompatButton` etc.

For these more simple Views (not counting for example SwitchCompat), what are the difference between them and the Android Framework version? I have not found any documentation on this matter...

I'm interested in knowing the consequences of choosing either version and if there are any advantages in chosing one over the other.

Specifically:

- Difference between `ListView` and `ListViewCompat`
- Difference between `Button` / `AppCompatButton`
- Difference between `ImageView` / `AppCompatImageView`
- Difference between `EditText` / `AppCompatEditText`
- Difference between `TextView` / `AppCompatTextView`

I changed from normal to AppCompat versions with the expectation that colors would be used from the theme and look the same on Lollipop and pre-lollipop, but it rather had the opposite effect on some views (such as ListView)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

AppCompat provides consistent UI support for older versions of APIs back to API v7.
from [Documentation](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html)

The full list of tint aware widgets available in appcompat

```
AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
AppCompatButton
AppCompatCheckBox
AppCompatCheckedTextView
AppCompatEditText
AppCompatMultiAutoCompleteTextView
AppCompatRadioButton
AppCompatRatingBar
AppCompatSpinner
AppCompatTextView
```

***ListViewCompat is subclass of ListView*** same others

---

edited:

[why both class available in framework or **How Android Support Library work**?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11972632/1168654)

Comment: Well I'm confused about why specific widgets are in this library at all when they are available on the Android Framework as well. I can understand the "tint aware" part...

Comment: @Joakim: i have edit answer and you will get answer why that class available in framework from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641669/how-android-support-library-work

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Answer (score 14):

If you use AppCompatActivity, then **AppCompatImageView** will automatically be used when you use **ImageView** in your layouts.

From the [AppCompatImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/appcompat/widget/AppCompatImageView) [AppCompatEditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/AppCompatEditText) [AppCompatButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/appcompat/widget/AppCompatButton)

**Button vs AppCompatButton**

> This will automatically be used when you use Button in your layouts
>   and the top-level activity / dialog is provided by appcompat. You
>   should only need to manually use this class when writing custom views.

**ImageView vs AppCompatImageView**

> This will automatically be used when you use ImageView in your layouts
>   and the top-level activity / dialog is provided by appcompat. You
>   should only need to manually use this class when writing custom views.

**EditText vs AppCompatEditText**

> This will automatically be used when you use EditText in your layouts
>   and the top-level activity / dialog is provided by appcompat. You
>   should only need to manually use this class when writing custom views.

and the same rule is also valid for other appcompat views